# Simplify the boolean equation using boolean algebra rules

Tags: boolean-algebra

If I have the boolean equation:

H = M'CD' + MC + MC' + CRD

I think I can combine so that it's

H = M'CD' + M(C + C') + CRD

Does C + C' go to simplify to zero? So, I'm left with

H = M'CD' + CRD

Comment: No, $C+C'$ simplifies to $1$, so $MC + MC'$ simplifies to $M$. Recall that the proposition "(I am sitting on a chair) or (I am not sitting on a chair)" is a tautology.

Comment: Thought so. That's what wikipedia was telling me too. So the final equation would be H = M'CD' + M + CRD? Anymore simplification to be done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) are your best friend. Otherwise, observe that:

$$ \begin{align*}
H &= M'CD' + M + CRD \\
&= M'CD' + M(1) + CRD \\
&= M'CD' + M(CD'+1) + CRD \\
&= M'CD' + MCD' + M + CRD \\
&= (M' + M)CD' + M + CRD \\
&= (1)CD' + M + CRD \\
&= CD' + M + CRD \\
&= CD' + CRD + M \\
&= C(1)D' + CRD + M\\
&= C(1 + R)D' + CRD + M\\
&= CD' + CRD' + CRD + M\\
&= CD' + CR(D' + D) + M\\
&= CD' + CR(1) + M\\
&= CD' + CR + M\\
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Actually, I used K maps to get the first boolean equation in my original post but I'm just not sure it's correct. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463314/deriving-truth-table-from-english-description

Comment: Could you also please help me on this problem: I have everything :( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463404/modify-boolean-equation-to-get-3-input-nor-equation-using-boolean-algebra-rules