# Deriving truth table from English description

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to check if my truth table is correct since it largely depends on further parts of a larger problem.

Here is the English description:

The controller will turn on the headlights under the following conditions:

$$\begin{array}{l}\text{The manual switch is on (ManualSwitch = ’1′)}\\
\text{or} \\
\text{The car is running (CarOn = ’1′) and:} \\
\quad\text{it is raining (Raining = ’1′),}\\
\quad\text{it is night time (Daytime = ’0′),}\\
\quad\text{or both.}\\
\text{or both.}
\end{array}$$
I'm representing it so that ManualSwitch = M, CarOn = C, Raining = R, Daytime = D, and HeadlightsOn = H. And X = Don't Care.

```
M     C     R     D     H
0     0     X     X     0
0     1     0     0     1
0     1     0     1     0
0     1     1     0     1
0     1     1     1     1
1     0     0     0     1
1     0     0     1     1
1     0     1     0     1
1     0     1     1     1
1     1     0     0     1
1     1     0     1     1
1     1     1     0     1
1     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by directly translating the English description to Boolean algebra, we obtain:
$$
H = M + C(R + D')
$$

Also, you should be able to condense the truth table to:

```
M     C     R     D     H
0     0     X     X     0
0     1     0     0     1
0     1     0     1     0
0     1     1     X     1
1     X     X     X     1
```

Comment: Cool, so it looks like I'm on the right track from this to the other problem.